# octobercms backend url give 404 error

Tags: php, octobercms

I am building a Octobercms plugin. I have create the form, but I want also to upload a image in the form.

I have link a modal to a input text box so I can browse and upload images. but the problem is what I try I get all the time a 404 error.

I create new content on the http://www.domain.com/admin/author-name/plugin-nam/plugin-name/create. The url work be fine, is see the form.

But my modal call a php script on http://www.domain.com/plugins/author-name/plugin-name/app/image-manager/image.php and I get then a 404 error.

I geuss I have to set something `routes.php` but I don't know what I have to set because I have `Route::get('*/file-manager/image.php'`, `'author-name\plug-name\app\file-manager\image.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AJAX framework to achieve this. Instead of calling a script try using a partial _image.htm. In the form attributes use data-request="onImageUpload" data-request-update="'image': '#image'" and in the create.htm use makePartial('image', ['image' => $image]) ?>

In the controller's constructor make a variable for $image and initially set it to null. Make a function onImageUpload() which has the image upload code and also sets this variable to the path of the uploaded image. So, now when you upload the image not only does it execute whatever custom code you have used in image.php inside the onImageUpload() itself rather than having a separate file image.php and also updates the image on load.

The partial _image.htm should have code as

```
{% if image %}
    <img src="{{image}}" />
{% endif %}
```

And the create.htm should have

```
<div id="image">{{ "{% partial \"image\" %}" }}</div>
```

Just where you want the image to appear